# Stationarity issue in Factor Analysis

Tags: stationarity, factor-analysis

I'm applying Exploratory Factor Analysis (EFA) on 20 variables to identify latent factors. The normalized data (Z-scores) is not stationary (Augmented Dickey-Fuller test). First differencing makes the data stationary, but it ruins the analysis because the Scree Plot indicates 15 latent factors. This is in contrast to 5 factors when EFA is run on the non-stationary normalized data. I assume first differencing breaks some relationships in the data. Although the results on EFA with 5 factors make sense, I'm still concerned that the EFA is performed on non-stationary data. Any suggestions or advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: When data include trends, then every item is apt to correlate with time, and thus inter-item correlations will be inflated compared to what one finds with differenced series.  Your 15 factors may be closer to the truth than your 5.

Comment: Thank you very much rolando2! I agree. Two questions if I may. 
1: The scree plot shows eigenvalue less than 1 at 7 factors, but it levels off only at factor 15. How should this be interpreted?
2: Even after differencing, the timeseries of one variable is still not stationary (10% significance level). Is it reasonable to still proceed with the EFA?
Your replies are much appreciated!

Comment: 1. At https://yellowbrickstats.com/documents/Factor%20Analysis%20Decision%20Guide.pdf you'll learn that scree plots are not foolproof and that the eigenvalue-greater-than-one criterion is a weak and outmoded way to select the number of factors.  2. I'd be remiss in giving more advice on that without knowing more of the situation. So much depends, too, on your purposes and on the expectations of your audience.